# How to filter a list in Kotlin using Regex

Tags: regex, kotlin

I've a list defined in Kotlin like following --

**`val spices = listOf("curry", "pepper", "cayenne", "ginger", "red curry", "green curry", "red pepper" )`**

Now I want to filter the spices which starts with `c` and ends with `e`. If I try below code, I get satisfactory result which is **`[cayenne]`** --

**`val filteredSpices = spices.filter { it.first() == 'c' && it.last() == 'e'}`**

But when I try following code, it returns an empty list ---

**`val filteredSpices = spices.filter { it.matches(Regex.fromLiteral("^[c].*[e]$")) }`**

I've tested the **Regex** before writing the solution. The Regex works fine but **fails to filter any element from the list**.

Why is it failing? What am I doing something wrong ?? I've tried the code on **`Intelli J Idea REPL`**.

People have suggested me to use **`Regex()`** instead of **`Regex.fromLiteral()`**, which works. But if we look under the hood below are the implementation for both of them ---

**`Regex()`  -- `public constructor(pattern: String): this(Pattern.compile(pattern))`**

**`Regex.fromLiteral()`  ---**
**`public fun fromLiteral(literal: String): Regex = literal.toRegex(RegexOption.LITERAL)`**

And the implementation of `literal.toRegex()` is like following ---

**`public inline fun String.toRegex(option: RegexOption): Regex = Regex(this, option)`**

They both actually returns a **`Regex`**. The only difference between both of the them is -- **`Regex.fromLiteral()`** returns a **Regex** with an option called **`RegexOption.LITERAL`**.

I want to understand why and how they differ exactly ??

Comment: Related/dupe: [What exactly does a Regex created with Regex.fromLiteral() match?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45035672) In short, `Regex.fromLiteral` is the wrong function to use. Create your regex with `Regex("^[c].*[e]$")`.

Comment: Your regex is quite baroque, too. What you need is `spices.filter { it.matches(Regex("c.*e")) }`. Another caveat is that you should definitely not create the regex inside the lambda. Use `val regex = Regex("c.*e")` and then `spices.filter { it.matches(regex) }`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, why shouldn't I create `regex` in lambda ?? As @Aran-Frey mentioned, that using `Reges()` instead of `Regex.formLiteral()` works. What's wrong in that  ?

Comment: Idiomatic is `"""someRegexThing""".toRegex()`

Comment: @Abhishek It's wasteful to create a regex object from scratch on each invocation of the filtering function. The pattern you supply will be parsed and compiled from scratch each time. But, if you absolutely don't care about performance, then it's fine.

Comment: @JaysonMinard The extra quotes are good when you have `\ ` in your pattern, otherwise they're just overhead. `.toRegex()` may have some advantage because you don't name the regex type directly, but `Regex(...)` is actually shorter to write, and reads quite well too. It's a public constructor on a public class... so it's public API.

Comment: @Abhishek About your added content in the question, it's far easier and quicker to just read the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex-option/-l-i-t-e-r-a-l.html) on that regex option instead of asking the world to copy-paste it for you.

Comment: Sorry @MarkoTopolnik, but I'm not asking the world to copy paste anything for me. I'm looking for an answer to a problem that I faced. As StackOverflow is a forum for Questions and Answers, I chose to put my question here. Before putting the question, I tried to find an answer. I couldn't find the exact answer so asked this question which is flagged as duplicate. I accept it as I have the answer now. Anyways, thanks for the documentation though. :)